# Validate types using templates at compilation time

Tags: c++, c++98

I would like to get a compiler error in case I pass a `float` number to my class that expect an `int` in the code below. The code below runs with gcc 4.9.3

```
gcc -std=c++98 -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0
```

How should I change the code that it will return compile error in case of different in types between the class instance type and the methods input argument type?

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class CheckValidity {
    public:
        CheckValidity(){};

        T isFoo(T variable)
        {
            T result = static_cast<T>(0);
            if ( variable > static_cast<T>(5) )
            {
                result = static_cast<T>(1);
            }
            return result;
        };
};

int main() {
    CheckValidity<int> checkValidityInt;
    std::cout << checkValidityInt.isFoo(6.0f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is -std=c++98 a hard requirement, or could you use any higher standard? Some sort of `typename std::enable_if`-magic should do the trick, but I'm not sure if it's available in C++98.

Comment: @Kent, i could use until C++03 standard. Unfortunately my embedded compiler does not support more then that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not getting a warning now is because the `float` value `6.0f` can be losslessly converted into an `int`. That is, you don't lose any precision during the conversion, because 6.0 can be exactly represented as 6. The compiler knows this because you are using compile-time constants.

If you changed it to `6.1f`, for example, you should get a warning (assuming you have `-Wconversion` enabled):

```
int main() {
    CheckValidity<int> checkValidityInt;
    std::cout << checkValidityInt.isFoo(6.1f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
In function 'int main()':  
20 : warning: conversion to 'int' alters 'float' constant value [-Wfloat-conversion]  
std::cout << checkValidityInt.isFoo(6.1f) << std::endl;
```

You would also get a warning if you were passing a variable of type `float`, rather than a constant. This means the warning should catch any potential problems. A precise conversion of a constant is not a real problem.

To convert this warning into an error (making sure you do not miss it), also pass the `-Werror` flag.

Answer (score 2):

For c++98:

One way to achieve what you want of requiring an exact match is to have a template method which accepts any type but always fails due to SFINAE:

```
    template<typename U>
    U isFoo(U variable)
    {
      typename CheckValidity::InvalidType x;
    }
```

For c++11:

You can use a deleted method to achieve the same effect more cleanly:

```
    template<typename U>
    U isFoo(U variable) = delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the member function a template member function. It opens up a few possibilities for dealing with different types.

---

Use `static_assert` and `std::is_floating_point` to make sure that the function is not called using floating point types.

```
template <typename U>
T isFoo(U variable)
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<U>::value == false,
                  "Can't handle floating point types");
    T result = static_cast<T>(0);
    if ( variable > static_cast<T>(5) )
    {
        result = static_cast<T>(1);
    }
    return result;
};
```

---

To make sure that `U` and `T` are the same type, you can use `std::is_same`:

```
template <typename U>
T isFoo(U variable)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, U>::value,
                  "Can't handle different types");
    T result = static_cast<T>(0);
    if ( variable > static_cast<T>(5) )
    {
        result = static_cast<T>(1);
    }
    return result;
};
```

---

To be able to deal with `U` being a derived type of `T`, you can use:

```
template <typename U>
T isFoo(U variable)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, U>::value,
                  "Can't handle incompatible types");
    T result = static_cast<T>(0);
    if ( variable > static_cast<T>(5) )
    {
        result = static_cast<T>(1);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: @CodyGray, I noticed the error right after I posted the answer. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template specialization:

```
//Returns false in the default case
template<typename V>
bool isFoo(V)
{
    return false;
};

//Returns true if the type passed is T
template<>
bool isFoo<T>(T)
{
    return true;
}
```

The variable is still passed as parameter without a name, because you don't need it internally. It is also still used because `isFoo<decltype(var)>()` is better than `isFoo(var)`.

---

If you can use C++11, use `std::is_same` or similar constructs:

```
//You need a separate type, because if you use T, you will just cast the result to T
template<typename V>
bool isFoo(V)
{
    //Compare the types
    return std::is_same<V, T>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is better achieved if you just leave common template class just declared, but not defined and specialize template class definition for float. I would try to play around something like type lists...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) in combination with [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/static_assert).

In whatever function or class template you want to restrict to integers, you can call:

```
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Integer required.");
```

You might also be interested in [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) (or the convenience typedef `enable_if_t`):

```
template <typename Integer,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>>
```

You can use call `static_assert` with any integer constant expression to generate a compile-time error if the expression is false. You can use `enable_if` to restrict the types with which a template can be instantiated (also causing a compiler error if you use an invalid type).

Edit: I just noticed that you're using -std=c++98. If you need to use that standard, I can delete this answer. But if you can use C++11, this will be better than what you can do in earlier standards.

Comment: my code should run on an embedded system, that is why i would like to avoid any type of asserts

Comment: Why would static asserts be a problem on an embedded system? They have absolutely no run-time cost, and would catch the error at compile-time. Seems like exactly what you would want for an embedded system...

Comment: Please don't delete your answer.  It is (probably) not useful for the original asker (unless it persuades him to move into this millennium), but it will probably be useful for people who search SO with a similar question.

Comment: @CodyGray, sorry. I thought of static_assert as an assert which stop your program on run-time. From searching a bit in the net, it seems that static_assert is only from c++11 and my embedded compiler support only until c++03 standard.

Comment: You can certainly simulate static assertions if C++11 is not available. Do it just like the C folks do it, by conditionally declaring an array with a negative size. Of course, then you'll need to emulate `std::is_integral`, which is not just difficult, just busy work.